# How to initialize an array in a class whose values can be used in constant-expressions?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initializer-list, constexpr

I would like to know how to initialize an array in a class whose values can be used in constant-expressions.
Here is an explanation of my problem :

```
// The goal : initializing an array for a class
// whose values can be used as normal static const
// (as template parameters for example)

class MyClass
{
    public:
        static const unsigned int value = 42; // <- No problem here
        static const unsigned int array[3] = {100, 101, 102}; // <- How to initialize this static const array (with constexpr or metaprogrammation maybe ?)
        template<unsigned int T> inline void f() {std::cout<<"Hello, my value is "<<T<<std::endl;} // <- Simple function for demonstration purposes
        inline void fvalue() {f<value>();} // <- No problem here
        inline void farray() {f<array[1]>();} // <- Big problem here
};
//const unsigned int Class1::array[3] = {100, 101, 102}; // <- If I do this, I will initialize the array but farray() will not compile
```

Is there any way to do this in C++ 2011 ? (with constexpr or metaprogrammation maybe ?)

Thank you very much !

EDIT : As the title specify it, I need the `array` to be a member of the class (not a global array).

Comment: Is [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/5a8cdc43416ce6ab11618e4d6047e40f) what you need? To be honest, I'm not 100% sure what's going on with that case of initialization, but it seems to work fine for the template.

Comment: This is just an example case. I need to have a array whose values can be used in constant-expressions for some CRTP, loop unrolling and optimizations purposes. But if we find the solution for this case, I will be able to use the same technique on my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can make it `constexpr`..

Making it `constexpr` allows the static member to have more types than just integral or enumeration types, when it is initialized in-class. In particular, the member just needs to be of a literal type, and all expressions in the initializer must be constant expressions. So this is fine

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        static constexpr unsigned int array[3] = {100, 101, 102};
        template<unsigned int T> inline void f() {
            std::cout<<"Hello, my value is "<<T<<std::endl;
        } // <- Simple function for demonstration purposes
        inline void farray() {f<array[1]>();}
};

// needs a definition out-of-class too. put it into a .cc file
constexpr unsigned int MyClass::array[3];
```

Comment: What version of gcc are you using (if you're using that)?  gcc 4.5.1 throws a bunch of compiler errors for me: http://ideone.com/Gm5hA

Comment: @Jason GCC4.5 did not yet sufficiently implement the constexpr proposals.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you were wondering what a meta-programming example could look like, here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<size_t... values>
struct number_list;

template<size_t value, size_t... values>
struct number_list<value, values...>
{
    static const size_t val = value;
    typedef number_list<values...> next;
};

template<size_t index, typename NumList>
struct indexer
{
    static const size_t val = indexer<index - 1, typename NumList::next>::val;
};

template<typename NumList>
struct indexer<0, NumList>
{
    static const size_t val = NumList::val;
};

template<typename NumList>
class MyClass
{
    public:
        template<size_t T> inline void f() 
        {
            std::cout << "Hello, my value is " << T << std::endl;
        }

        inline void farray() {f<indexer<1, NumList>::val>();}
};

int main()
{
        MyClass<number_list<3, 5, 6>> a;
        a.farray();
        return 0;
}
```